Increase line sharpness in Plotly to same level as axes/text
I've noticed that narrow vertical/horizontal lines in Plotly are not as sharp as the axis lines or text when displayed in a Jupyter notebook. Is there any way to change the sharpness? I wondered whether it might be anti-aliasing, but I couldn't find a way to turn it off.
Minimal example:
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=[0, 0],
        y=[1, 2],
        mode="lines",
        line=dict(shape="linear", color="black", width=1),
    )
)

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis2=dict(domain=[0.55, 0.9], anchor="y2", linecolor="black"),
    yaxis2=dict(domain=[0.55, 0.9], anchor="x2", linecolor="black"),
)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0], y=[1], xaxis="x2", yaxis="y2"))

fig.show(renderer="notebook")

Below is the resulting plot in a Jupyter Notebook in VS Code on Windows showing the soft vertical line in contrast to the sharp axes and text.

Only when I zoom in significantly does the sharpness of the line match the axes.


If you do not specify the shape, which is a line parameter, in your initial line chart specification, do you not get the intended result?　line=dict(color="black", width=1),#shape="linear"

Unfortunately not. I tried setting shape="linear" to see whether it improves anything.

I have determined that shape is not needed because I have checked this reference. If you do not set the line shape, you will see a thicker blue line.
